# Setting an alias for a shell script, located in one of my folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

So I have this folder BashScripts that has the following directory path

```
/home/sadnan/BashScripts
```

`/home/sadnan` being my `$HOME`. This is where I intend to put my custom shell scripts. Currently there is only one named `cbi.sh`. The script works as expected when I run from inside the folder. Now I want to be able to run it globally. So I added the following to my .bashrc file

```
#For my personal Bash Scripts
if [ -d $HOME/BashScripts ]; then
 PATH="$PATH:$HOME/BashScripts"
fi

alias cbi='. ./cbi.sh'
```

So now when I do `echo $PATH` it prints out the following

```
/home/sadnan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/sadnan/BashScripts
```

So the folder seems to be added to the PATH. Which if I understand correctly should allow me to run my shell scripts globally.

And then I have also setup up an alias for the script and named it `cbi`

But now when I run `cbi` or `./cbi.sh` on my terminal, this is what I get

```
bash: ./cbi.sh: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong, I haven't done much shell scripting. But I thought this was the way to go.

I have also tried `` alias cbi=`source ./cbi.sh' `` and `` alias cbi=`sh ./cbi.sh' ``
Neither of which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./cbi.sh` means "run cbi.sh from the current directory".  So if you are not in `/home/sadnan/BashScripts` it will not work, since it cannot find `cbi.sh` in the current directory.

To confirm that your PATH is correctly set, execute `which cbi.sh`.  It should return `/home/sadnan/BashScripts/cbi.sh`.

If you **must** have an alias, you could do `alias cbi='/home/sadnan/BashScripts/cbi.sh'`.  This is the easiest way to ensure proper execution.

For all of the above to work, `cbi.sh` must be executable (`chmod u+x cbi.sh`).

---

If you want to source it (`. cbi.sh`) instead of calling it like an executable define your alias like so:

```
alias cbi='. /home/sadnan/BashScripts/cbi.sh'
```

Research the difference between executing and "sourcing" a script.

**EDIT**: I removed this text, following @Diego's comment.

> your PATH variable will not be used at all.  You should then remove
>   the PATH addition, and

Comment: Correction: The pathnames
    in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME when you use `source FILENAME` or `. FILENAME`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this detail, I did not know!  I will edit the answer!

Comment: Thank you, and you are right I do not want to source it. Just execute it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run `cbi.sh`:

```
# Wrong, the file is not named 'cbi'
cbi

# Wrong, the file is not in the current directory
./cbi.sh

# Wrong, same reason as above
alias cbi='. ./cbi.sh'
cbi

# Correct, this is the name of the file:
cbi.sh
```

Comment: Alternately, you could rename the script to just `cbi`, then use that as the command to run it. Unix programs -- including shell scripts -- normally do not have extensions.